# how to use proxy in inet in vb6?

Tags: vb6

I'm making a program in vb6.
i;d like to connect using a proxy through inet in vb6. how to o it? please help.

thank you

Comment: You'd like to connect to what?  Are you trying to download a file from the internet in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a more or less generic function to open an internet connection that can take proxy parameters. It is a good example of how a proxy is used.

```
Private Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "WinInet" Alias "InternetOpenA" (ByVal lpszAgent As String, ByVal lpAccessType As Long, ByVal lpszProxyName As String, ByVal lpszProxyBypass As String, ByVal lpFlags As Long) As Long

Public Function OpenInternet(ByVal sAppName As String, ByVal lAccessType As Long,  ByVal sProxyName As String, _
   ByVal sProxyBypass As String, ByVal lFlags As Long) As Boolean
   Dim Rtn As Long
   Dim lngINetHandle As Long
   Dim strHeaders As String
   Dim lngDllErr As Long

   On Error GoTo errOpenInternet

   RaiseEvent Operation("Opening internet connection")
   Rtn = InternetOpen(ByVal sAppName, ByVal lAccessType, ByVal sProxyName, ByVal sProxyBypass, ByVal lFlags)

   If Rtn = 0 Then   'failed for some reason
      lngDllErr = Err.LastDllError
      If lngDllErr <> 0 Then
         RaiseEvent Operation("Error " & CStr(lngDllErr))
         Err.Raise lngDllErr, "OpenInternet", ErrorOut(Err.LastDllError, "OpenInternet")
      End If
   Else
      RaiseEvent Operation("Connection opened")
      InternetHandle = Rtn
      ExtendedError = ""
   End If

   OpenInternet = CBool(Rtn)

   Exit Function

errOpenInternet:
   Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source & ":OpenInternet", Err.Description

End Function
```